# Swagger Hub `Try it out` returns TypeError: Failed to fetch for localhost when using browser option

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

I am trying to test my API documentation using `openapi: 3.0.1` format. When trying to execute the endpoints from Swagger Hub documentation, I get `TypeError: Failed to fetch`.

The curl command that is shown runs fine from terminal:

```
curl -X GET "http://localhost:3030/services" -H "accept: application/json; charset=UTF-8"
```

The issue is both for Safari as well as Chrome browsers.

I have also enabled CORS for my golang application as per the following snippet:

```
allowedOrigins := handlers.AllowedOrigins([]string{"*"})
allowedCredentials := handlers.AllowCredentials()
exposedHeaders := handlers.ExposedHeaders([]string{"Content-Length", "ETag", "Link", "X-RateLimit-Limit", "X-RateLimit-Remaining"})

log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":3030", handlers.CORS(allowedOrigins, allowedCredentials, exposedHeaders)(router)))
```

[image]

Comment: Could you check the error message in the browser console? It's probably not a CORS issue, but the browser blocking requests to HTTP sent from an HTTPS origin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Failed to fetch" means CORS is misconfigured. Specifically,

```
allowedOrigins := handlers.AllowedOrigins([]string{"*"})
```

means that your server always returns

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

but according to the [SwaggerHub documentation](https://app.swaggerhub.com/help/ui/cors) you should return

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://app.swaggerhub.com
Vary: Origin
```

> **Access-Control-Allow-Origin**
>
> The value of this header must be set as follows:
>
> - If the request contains a non-empty `Origin` header (as in case of requests sent from a browser, such as “try it out” requests), return this origin along with the `Vary: Origin` header:
>
>   ```
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://host.from.which.the.request.came
>   Vary: Origin
>   ```
> - If the request does not have `Origin`, return the `*` wildcard:
>
>   ```
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
>   ```